# Unit conversion library in .Net

Tags: .net, math

Is there a .Net library for unit conversion?

Comment: What kind of unit conversion?

Comment: math units like length/mass/speed/temperature etc...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027673/net-units-class-inches-to-millimeters

Answer (score 5):

[Yes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/Measurement_Conversion.aspx). I have not used this, but it claims to do conversions.

Comment: It's really a framework that can handle different units, I'm looking for a full library so that I don't have to gather all data for conversions. Does such a database exist?

Answer (score 1):

As there is no accepted answer yet: http://www.gnu.org/software/units/