# How to Convert Inch unit to Fraction unit in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-conversion

I have created an application in WPF which convert `Imperial to Metric` and `Metric to Imperial` units. I have data in `Inch` unit now this value i want to convert it in `Fraction` unit. I have searched but not got any specific formula to implement.

Any idea?

1)    Eg: 39.75
    Output:100921⁄32mm

**Note: Input value is in inch i.e 39.75 inch and out put is in fraction unit.**

**[See Conversion Chart](http://www.metric-conversions.org/length/inches-to-millimeters-table.htm)**

Comment: When asking about fractions, __O/p__ is not a handy notation for output.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give this solution a look.

```
    public class Length
{
    private double const MillimetersPerInch = 25.4;
    private double _Millimeters;

    public static Length FromMillimeters(double mm)
    {
         return new Length { _Millimeters = mm };
    }

    public static Length FromInch(double inch)
    {
         return new Length { _Millimeters = inch * MillimetersPerInch };
    }

    public double Inch { get { return _Millimeters / MillimetersPerInch; } } 
    public double Millimeters { get { return _Millimeters; } }
}
```

[.NET units class, inches to millimeters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027673/net-units-class-inches-to-millimeters)